# Find Week Number in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am creating a forecast of orders for the year 2021 and breaking it out by week.

I am using

```
SELECT DATEPART(WK,'2021-01-01')
```

to find my weeks however i am running into an issue where 2021-01-01 through 2021-01-03 actually fall into week 53 of year 2021. is there a way i can tell sql to mark those dates as week 53 and start on the 4th as week 1?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are looking for the "iso_week" option on [`datepart()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datepart-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15):

```
select datepart(iso_week, '2021-01-01')
```

Getting the ISO year, unfortunately, is trickier, but that is not your question.

Comment: SELECT YEAR(DATEADD(day, 26 - DATEPART(iso_week, '2021-01-04'), '2021-01-04')) , Get the year from this and use the above to get the week